# How to determine averages by multiple criteria including ignoring zeros in the calculations

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create an averageifs statement that will go through a dataset and for each month, calculate the average (ignoring zero values) of two different columns). I'm not sure how to add a sample dataset to this question?

=averageifs(b:b, ">0", c:c, "Fresh") ... yields "you've entered too few arguments for this function."

also tried: =averageifs(b:b,  ">0", a:a, e2, c:c, f1) ... same result

One can be downloaded from here: https://image-files-manausa.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/Stack_Overflow_Example.xlsx

A screen capture is below:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain how you used `AVERAGEIFS` and how it didn't solve your problem?

Comment: I tried several different attempts and could not even get it to accept the attempt; I rec'd the error expecting different arguments.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76325436/edit) and _show_ us these attempts

Comment: I thought this would be easy with a pivotable, but I could not figure out how to tell it to ignore zero values in the data when determining the average.

Comment: =averageifs(b:b, ">0", c:c, "Fresh")

Comment: You need to specify the range you want to average before putting in criterias: `=averageifs(b:b, b:b, ">0", c:c, "Fresh")` See the [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/averageifs-function-48910c45-1fc0-4389-a028-f7c5c3001690)

Comment: also ">"&0 works...

Comment: Thanks @Cybernetic.nomad, that helps a lot. How do I then break it down by month?

Answer (score 1):

Just to show 3 ways of setting criteria in averageifs() or any of the xxxifs() functions:

[image]

I use the 3rd version where a cell is referenced as that is the most flexible.

Comment: Thank you Solar Mike. This only address one condition though? In my example, I am trying to determine the average each month (A column) using non-zero values in the B column.

Comment: @JoeManausa then add criteria as you need to control what you want  - you might find month() handy as well.

Comment: I don't understand how to add the second set of criteria @SolarMike ... I basically need it to be =AVERAGEIFS(B2:B35,B2:B35,">0") for every month in the A column.

Comment: FWIW, I tried this (and failed): =AVERAGEIFS(a2:a35,a2:a35,month(e2),B2:B35,B2:B35,">0")

Comment: This gets the result broken down by Type, but I need it further broken down by month and year? =AVERAGEIFS(B:B, B:B, ">0", C:C, F$1)

Answer (score 0):

I added a few named ranges to keep my head from spinning. This is a working solution:

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(Time,Time,">0",Dates,">="&E2,Dates,"<="&EDATE(E2,1),Type,$F$1),"")
```

Where Dates is a2:a35
Time is b2:b35
Type is c2:c35